# Radial Force Understanding

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics

I am having trouble understanding how *radial force* works. I am working in a dynamics course so there's always centripetal acceleration.

My difficulty comes from two cases.

1. Analyzing a car traveling over a hill, it crosses the peak at maximum possible speed (Normal force is 0 N). Here my professors vector diagram had only weight downwards and no radial force.
2. A helical slide, having a person traveling down. Here I was asked to work out a radial force which is equal to $mv^2/R$.

My question is why was there no radial force included when the car traveled over the top of the hill, why there is a radial force in case 2 and most importantly, when will there be a radial force?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider it helpful to include the phrase "... **acts as** central force" when talking/thinking about such problems.

There are many forces (gravity, tension in a string, ...) that may or may not act as a central force.

Considering your examples:

1. Crossing the hill (in the shape of a circle?): An object moves along a circle only if a constant central force is acting on it. Here it is gravity. Gravity always acts on an object on earth and when it's gravity that's keeping the car on the ground on a circular road, gravity **acts as** central force. One could draw two arrows in the diagram (one for the gravitational force and another one for the central force), but that might be confusing because they are the same thing.
2. Helical slide: here gravity does not help that much. But there must be a central force because we see the circular motion. Here it's a little bit more complicated: the person exerts an outward force on the outer wall because it "is in the way". The wall therefore exerts a force of equal magnitude and opposite in direction on the person (Newton's third law). This force **acts as** central force because it points to the center of the helix and forces the person on the circular path. On could draw several arrows in this situation: force of person onto the wall (outwards), reaction force of wall onto person (inwards), central force (again the same thing as the reaction force).

Comment: Should you also mention the normal force in the hill example? Only a component of the weight is a central force in this case, and the normal force can also be viewed as a central force, except pointing away from the center.

Comment: Good point... Maybe I'll create a sketch for this one...

Comment: Thank you, I understand now that other forces act as a radial force. Thank you for your assistance. Regarding the hill though, the car crosses at a maximum speed, the normal force is 0. Kind Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

In the car example the radial force is the gravitational force, since this force is pointing towards the center of the circle.

In general, for an object that is changing direction, any force component perpendicular to the motion of the object can be viewed as a radial force. A radial force is its own type of force, like how gravity or friction are forces. Any force (or it least a component) can be considered "radial" if it has a radial component, i.e. perpendicular to the the velocity.

Comment: So, if there is a clearly present force, like weight, I should assume this is the Radial force, but if there are no forces in the radial direction that are like weight etc, and the object moves in a circle, then I say that the force causing that rotation is a radial force?

Comment: @TeyashArjun If there are no forces in the radial direction then the object cannot move in a circle. Circular motion requires a force acting perpendicular to the motion. If your object is moving in a circle, any force that points towards or away from the center of the circle is a radial force, but there has to always be at least one force pointing towards the center of the circle to have circular motion at all. There can be other forces as well. You don't need to come up with any rules or special things to memorize. Just see if the force is perpendicular to the motion or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the terms, especially in your comment.

You should begin with Newton second law: $\Sigma F= ma$. For ***any*** circular-type motion this can be stated as $\Sigma F=m\frac{v^2}{r}$.

On the left hand side you should include all real radial forces (weight, normal, etc...). The sum of these forces will determine the radial acceleration $\frac{v^2}{r}$